# meteor is not recognized as internal or external command on window 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, meteor

When I issue `meteor --help` on the window 7 command prompt, I get the error stated in this post's title.
However it works if I am logged in to my machine as an admin or as another used. I copied the path for the .meteor folder from the other user Environment Variable and pasted it in my Environment Variable for no avail. The path is the location where the .meteor is located.

I must add that this user account has just been created but the other uses have been there before.

What else can I try? Thanks